# Separate style for markdown in single backticks vs. triple backticks using the Minima theme for Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, minima, jekyll-theme

I am trying to customize the Minima theme for Jekyll. I'd like to have a dark background for code between triple backticks (i.e. in its own paragraph), but I don't want to affect the background of inline code between single backticks. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An inline code block in Markdown renders as:

```
<code>Lorem ipsum</code>
```

A fenced code block - the triple backticks - renders as:

```
<pre><code>Lorem ipsum</code></pre>
```

Following is an example of CSS selectors targeting theses patterns. You can see these behaviours in my example:

- `<code>` tag on it's own is less specific than the `<pre><code>` pattern, the background-colour of the fenced code style overrides the background colour of the inline block
- the `<code>` pattern also matches the `<pre><code>` pattern, as a subset, so the font-weight bold rule applied to `<code>` CSS rule, also applies to `<pre><code>`
- since the `color: Blue;` attribute only applies to `<pre><code>`, it's the only one with blue text

```css
code {
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: GreenYellow;
}

pre > code {
  background-color: AliceBlue;
  color: Blue;
}
```

```html
<code>Lorem ipsum</code>

<pre><code>Lorem ipsum</code></pre>
```

In summary, if you want to apply a rule to the fenced code block but not the inline code block, use a more specific CSS selector, like `pre > code`. This selector matches `<code>` blocks where the parent is a `<pre>` tag.

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to specify this as a customization/extension on top of the original theme definition, as described [here](https://docs.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/adding-a-theme-to-your-github-pages-site-using-jekyll#customizing-your-themes-css)? I'd like to be able to do something like this that can be applied as a delta/extension to any of the GH Pages themes, instead of having to copy the whole theme definition into my own site and edit it there.